# Turning on verbose logging in AutoCad 2011

Tags: logging, autocad, autocad-plugin

I have an AutoCad addon. The addon folder is added to the support file search path but when launched under a Power User autocad doesn't automatically load the addon.

I'm looking for a way to troubleshoot the problem so I turned to logging. In the options dialog on the Files tab I have Log File Location specified. It is inside the user's profile folder so the user should have rights to write to this folder.

When I launch Autocad I expect it to write to the specified log file but no log file is created. I suppose the logging is just turned of or has a low level of verbosity to show the addon related info.

How do I configure autocad so that it writes verbose logs allowing to debug addon loading failures?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoCAD only write the contents of the text window when you enable the log. So it won't help you to debug the loading of your addon.